# Replace d3.js symbols with images

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Referring to this **fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/andycooper/a7as6/)**:

I need to replace the symbols with images...or possibly a single image at first..like for instance, this image:

```
https://github.com/favicon.ico
```

What I am trying in the code is as follows:

```
vis.selectAll("path")
     .data(nodes)
   .enter().append("path")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
     .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
       .attr("x", -8)
       .attr("y", -8)
       .attr("width", 16)
       .attr("height", 16)
       .style("stroke", "black")
       .style("stroke-width", "1px")
       .call(force.drag);
```

It is appending  `image` tag to each of the `path` tags, but not showing up the image itself. Any hints?

Comment: do i need to append("g") element instead of "image"?

Comment: Is [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/950642) what you mean?

Comment: yes..its the closest example actually where nodes are replaced by names. In my jsfiddle example, I have nodes forced in as symbols. I need to replace them with images. Please look at the fiddle link I added at the top of question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "nodes are replaced by names".  In the link I posted, the nodes are images.  What do you want to do differently from that example?

Comment: That was a typo..it was 'nodes are replaced by images'. My example is very similar, but if you see on the fiddle I have added, I am trying something similar as it is done in the example you mentioned. But its not working somehow..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're appending each image as a child of each path. What you probably want is to append a group that contains both a path and an image (which I think is what you were asking in your first comment).

Something like this:

```
var groups = vis.selectAll("g")
    .data(nodes).enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(force.drag);

groups.append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
        .size(function(d) { return d.size; })
        .type(function(d) { return d.type; }))
    .style("fill", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

groups.append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", "https://github.com/favicon.ico")
       .attr("x", -8)
       .attr("y", -8)
       .attr("width", 16)
       .attr("height", 16)
       .style("stroke", "black")
       .style("stroke-width", "1px");
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/findango/a7as6/4/