# Complex symbols within a single node in d3.js, where symbols depend on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There are examples of using different shapes for different nodes in graph layouts using d3.js (e.g. [Different node symbols for d3.js force-directed graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855794/different-node-symbols-for-d3-js-force-directed-graph)). There is also an example of combining a symbol and image together in a single node ([Replace d3.js symbols with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976895/replace-d3-js-symbols-with-images)).

Is there any way to include multiple shapes within a single node, where the shapes contained in the node depend on that node's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, a "node" in the d3 force layout is just an abstraction.

A node will be given x and y properties by the layout, and you could just as easily use these properties to translate a `<g>` element that contains multiple symbols.

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/bamawe/2/edit?js,output) is a simple example of this.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that I would need a for loop or something. If I want to use an a combination of image, path, and built in shapes, would I still select symbols like this?`groups.selectAll('.symbol').data(function(d) {return d.data;}`

Comment: Perhaps. It depends what kind of data you are using. Do you have any example data?

Comment: Data is going to be for a family tree, and the json will be in a tree structure. var tree = {name: "grandparents name",  spouses: [{name: "first wife"}, {name: "2nd wife"}], children: [{name:"parent1", spouses:[{name:"parent2"}], children:[{name:"sister" }, {name:"brother"}]}]}

Comment: I typed the above from my phone, so I hope the formatting isn't too atrocious, but I think it gives the idea. I want to put spouses within the same node and use the built in tree layout for the ancestor relationships

Comment: Also, there will be images for each person (multiple images per tree node)